# Can you use "new" and "prospective" together?

Tags: phrase-usage

I just read this news—*AIIB Welcomes New Prospective Members*.

Aren't new and prospective contradicting each other? If you are a new member, you can not be a prospective member.

Comment: How do you think they contradict each other?

Comment: The strong collocation 'new members' hinders the reading 'new [prospective members]'. But the people queuing up to join this month _**are**_ new prospective members when compared with those queuing up to join four years ago. // The fact that, as you say, prospective members can't at the same time be prospective members _forces_ the 'new [prospective members]' interpretation.